# Componentes não estão na classe R

Tags: android, android-studio

Estou construindo uma agenda, e para isso criei uma `Activity` onde ficaria uma lista com todos os contatos:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".actContato">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtPesquisa"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/lbl_hint_nome_pesquisa"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imb_ADD"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstContatos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

E outra `Activity` onde seria cadastrado todos os contatos:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="aula4.com.example.raru.agenda.ActContatos">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnlNome"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtNomeContato"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lblNomeContato"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtNome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/lbl_hint_nome"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edtSobreNome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/lbl_hint_sobrenome"
            android:inputType="textPersonName" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnlTelefone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtTelefone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lblTelefone"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtTelefone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="phone" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnTelefone"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnlEmail"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lblEmail"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtEmail"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnEmail"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnlEndereco"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtEndereco"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lblEndereco"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtEndereco"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnEndereco"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnlDatasEspeciais"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtDatas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lblDatas"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtDatas"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="date" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spnDatas"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/lnlGrupo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtGrupos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/lblGrupos"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtGrupos"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="text" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Porém na hora de pegar a referencia nas classes java de ambas as `Activity` (`findViewById()`), é apontado que não há referencia para os componentes do xml.

Dei uma olhada na classe R e realmente nao há a referencia deles.

OBS: Lembrei que esse erro só veio a acontecer após editar o xml do menu, antes eu conseguia até realizar testes pela maquina virtual, já retirei todas as modificações e deixei o xml como antes:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="aula4.com.example.raru.agenda2.ActContatos">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

e:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".actContato">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Erros:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Verifica se existe erros no seu arquivo de layout e de um clean no projeto

Comment: eu havia feito isso antes de perguntar, porém o erro sempre persiste.

Answer (score 1):

Tente o seguinte, comente ou remova todas as linhas com erros, dê um clean em seu projeto e depois build. Provavelmente os elementos irão reaparecer na classe R.

A classe R é gerada automaticamente tendo nela todos os elementos de seus layouts, porém em alguns tipos de erros no seu código ela pode não ser gerada ou não totalmente.

Comment: eu tentei, e realmente foram criados os componentes corretamente na classe R. Porém o erro ainda persiste.

Comment: Você tem certeza que está digitando o nome corretamente ou que não tem nenhum erro no seu layout?

Comment: eu até copiei e colei os nomes, e no layout eu não encontrei, até postei aqui para ver se alguém reparava em algo.

Comment: Realmente estranho, abre o seu act_contato que também não está sendo encontrado e posta a print aqui na dúvida

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/9iIlV.png<br/>

<br/>act_Contato Renderizada:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/UtJDU.png<br/>
act_Contatos Renderizada:
http://i.stack.imgur.com/XBjQw.png

Comment: Então amigo pelo que vi a sua classe actContato.java está com o nome errado pois deveria iniciar com maiúscula e no act_contatos.xml no LinearLayout você colocou em tools:context="aula4.com.example.raru.agenda.ActContatos"> 


Mas pelo que entendi o seu projeto é aula4.com.example.raru.agenda2 (Tem um 2 no final)
Logo deveria ser: tools:context="aula4.com.example.raru.agenda.ActContatos">

De resto a primeiro momento não vejo outros erros. Veja se isso resolve. Se sim, por favor marque a resposta como útil.

Comment: Jean. o numero 2 é por que na primeira tentativa aconteceu o erro, e na hora eu pensei que deveria ser algum bug relacionado com a IDE, sendo assim criei um segundo projeto (esse) e copiei tudo q havia criado. Porém o erro persistiu. Tentei a sua dica e também não funcionou.

Comment: Bom amigo, então esgotou-se minhas alternativas. Como uma possível solução para prosseguir eu recomendo criar um novo projeto e não copiar os elementos ou senão copiar mas alterar o nome para que fique de acordo com o contexto do novo projeto e não do antigo.

Answer (score 1):

O erro não é na geração da classe R ou no layout e sim no arquivo build.gradle, ou seja, o seu arquivo de configuração de build do projeto. As duas imagens que você postou mostram claramente que o erro não tem nada a ver com o layout. Certifique-se de corrigir os erros indicados no painel inferior esquerdo da segunda imagem e de escrever corretamente seu arquivo de build. Depois que tudo estiver corrigido, dê um clean + rebuild no projeto.

Comment: Eu arrumei o erro, fiz o clean e rebuild, porém não mudou em nada.

Answer (score 0):

Tente duas coisas:

1º No Android Studio clique em "Build" e depois em "Clean Project"
2º Clique novamente em "Build" clique em "Rebuild Project"

Veja se resolve

Comment: Infelizmente não resolveu. A única saída que consegui, foi recriar o projeto.